# Printing array to blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm getting an error of

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.

I'm trying to print an `array` from `session` to blade.

view:

```
<input type="text" name="to" value="{{$mail}}">
```

controller:

```
public function view_send_email()
{
    $data["_email_list"] = Tbl_press_release_email::get();
    $data["sent_email"] = Request::input('sent_email');
    $mail = Session::get('email');

    return view("send_email", compact('data', 'mail'));
}
```

Comment: `var_dump` the mail variable to see what is it's content and put it in the comments.

Comment: Under the line `$mail = Session::get('email');`, place `dd($mail);` and see what's inside

Comment: `array:1 [▼
  "_email" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "pantek@sph.com.sg"
    1 => "yapwq@sph.com.sg"
    2 => "ai@buro247.sg"
  ]
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
@foreach ($mail as $email)
    <input type="text" name="to[]" value="{{$email}}">
@endforeach
```

**Note**: As you will have multiple values in `$email` you need to take array of input element as mentioned in above code (i.e `name = "to[]"`)

**Updated Answer**

```
@foreach ($mail as $email)
   @foreach ($mail as $emails)
        <input type="text" name="to[]" value="{{$emails}}">
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: `array:1 [▼ "_email" => array:3 [▼ 0 => "pantek@sph.com.sg" 1 => "yapwq@sph.com.sg" 2 => "ai@buro247.sg" ] ]` sample of my `array`. i want to put all the value of the array in one input

Comment: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/html/digimahouse/resources/views/member/email_system/send_email_press_release.blade.php)`still getting this error.

Comment: @nethkennnnn: Please display blade file code for send_email_press_r‌​elease.blade.php file

Comment: `@foreach ($mail as $email)
   <input type="text" id="input_subject" placeholder="decrypt" class="form-control email-to-container subject_email" name="to" value="{{$email}}">
@endforeach`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/html/digimahouse/resources/views/member/email_system/send_email_press_release.blade.php)` still getting

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="to" value="{{$mail}}">

To

<input type="text" name="to" value="{{print_r($mail)}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's returning multiple values, so you have to loop through them to display all of them, use a `foreach` loop.

```
@foreach ($mail as $email)
    <input type="text" name="to" value="{{$email}}">
@endforeach
```

If you want Form Model Binding

That's a different thing but the same concept, you can view the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding).

**EDIT**: It looks like you want to store an array into an input, to do this you must add a `[]` at the end of the name of your input like this

```
<input type="text" name="to[]" value="{{$mail}}">
```

Then when they submit you simply go `Input::get('to')[0]` to display the first input.

Comment: I want to store all the data in one `input`. i think using `foreach loop` will make the input increments.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/html/digimahouse/resources/views/member/email_system/send_email_press_release.blade.php)` still getting this error